# vb.net scope_identity is DBNull

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scope-identity

I have this code. I want to take the id of the insert statement and store in a variable.
I can't use SqlDataSource so I only can use DataTableReader and I'm not familiar with handling SCOPE_IDENTITY in DataTableReader...

```
Dim sql As String = "insert into tbl_url (url) values ('" & Request.RawUrl & "')"
    'Helper is a class of mine, don't mind it
    Helper.execQuery(sql)
    sql = "select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id"
    Dim dtr As Data.DataTableReader
    dtr = Helper.getDataTableReader(sql)
    Dim code As Decimal
    If dtr.Read Then
        code = dtr("id")
    End If
    dtr.Close()
```

dtr("id") is DBNull... why?

EDIT:

As said by Damien_The_Unbeliever, in the Helper the connection closes, so these are two different scopes...

Does anyone know how to store in a variable the SCOPE_IDENTITY only with DataTableReader?

Comment: `Helper` is probably quite relevant - at a guess, it opens a connection, runs the SQL and then closes the connection. Meaning your two bits of SQL are running in different scopes. Which, as you may guess from part of the name, means that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` isn't going to work.

Comment: maybe you're right, I'll try!

Comment: yeah, that's right... helper closes the connection. do you know how to take the scope_identity without the helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already identified in your comments, Helper is closing the connection between the two queries, causing each query to execute in it's own scope. This is why [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) doesn't find your ID.

There are a couple of options:

[`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) - This will return the last ID inserted in any table in the current session. However, this might have the same issue.

[`IDENT_CURRENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) - This returns the last ID inserted in a specified table, across any session. However, this is not necessarily *your* ID (it could be another person doing another insert.

Both of these have issues, however. You might be better off returning the ID directly from your query. On a related note - you should not concatenate your data into the SQL string - this opens you up to sql injection attacks. Instead, you should use Sql Parameters.

Below is an example that is roughly what you need to do. Obviously, I've coded this as straight up ADO.Net - you will need to work out how this fits in with your Helper class.

```
Dim sql As String = "insert into tbl_url (url) values (@url); Select @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
Dim id As String = String.Empty

Dim sqlcmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
sqlcmd.Connection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your Connection String here")
sqlcmd.Connection.Open()
sqlcmd.CommandText = sql
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("url", Request.RawUrl))


Dim idParam = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("ID", id)
idParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(idParam)

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

'Get the Value from the output parameter
id = idParam.Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer! Now I have a clear view of the situation and I'll find out the best solution for my project! :)